# Sorting Excel columns to the left, based on how many cels are populated

Tags: excel, sorting, vba

I have an Excel2013 worksheet that includes user’s names down the side, the names of the AD Security Groups they’re each a member of across the top, and an “X” in the cel if the user is in the group.  Something like this:

```
           AllUsers ITgroup DistroList Admins
Jason       X       X       X
Srinivas    X               X          X
Mary        X       X       X          X
Tyler       X       X       X
```

I’d like to sort the columns from left to right depending on how many users are in that group, so the result would look like this:

```
           AllUsers DistroList  ITgroup     Admins
Jason       X       X           X
Srinivas    X       X                       X
Mary        X       X           X           X
Tyler       X       X           X
```

(Notice how "ITgroup" and "DistroList" have switched places, since there are more users in DistroList.)

I don’t have empty columns, as those have already been removed (along with their column headers); there are a couple hundred columns, but each one will have at least one ‘X’ in it somewhere.

There are some other columns that I left out of the example (email, logon, etc)
A macro would be ideal but I’d be ok with manipulating the data manually if I could figure out how to do it!  All suggestions welcome!

Comment: What is the scope (aka total columns and total rows) of your actual data? An appropriate answer depends on how many items to process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pick me, Pick Me...lol.

It sounds like a basic bubble sort to me. So here it is:

```
Sub BubbleSortColumns()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim lastColumn As Long, lLeft As Long, lRight As Long

    lastColumn = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

    For lRight = 2 To lastColumn
        For lLeft = lRight + 1 To lastColumn
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(lLeft)) > WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(lRight)) Then
                Columns(lLeft).Cut
                Columns(lRight).Insert Shift:=xlToRight

            End If
        Next
    Next

    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Bingo - this worked perfectly, Thomas.  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

I received the best results from using a combination of the [Range.Sort method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840646.aspx) with a combination of xlTopToBottom and xlLeftToRight orientations.

[image: reorderLeftToRight]
                <sup>Sample data before reorderLeftToRight sub</sup>

```
Sub reorderLeftToRight()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long
    With Worksheets("Sheet16")
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            For c = 2 To .Columns.Count
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Columns(c), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
            Next c
            For r = 2 To .Rows.Count
                .Cells.Sort Key1:=.Rows(r), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Orientation:=xlLeftToRight, Header:=xlYes
            Next r
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: reorderLeftToRight_after]
                <sup>Sample data after reorderLeftToRight sub</sup>

Slightly different results were achieved by reversing the order of one or both of the [For ... Next](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ebk1751.aspx) statements.

Comment: `reorderLeftToRight` is sorting the columns based on the last non-empty cell not by group count.  If D5 is the only non-empty cell in column D and B2:B4 are filled but B5 is empty column D will be moves to the left Column B.

Comment: Thanks Jeeped - I actually ran into some trouble with this, where I'd get a message "subscript out of range" - I have to confess that I don't have a lot of background in VBA to troubleshoot this, but debug takes me to the line "With Worksheets("Sheet16")" - I tried changing this to "Sheet4", as this is the one I'm working on, in my workbook, but no dice.  Just thought I'd give some feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Put a count on the bottom row, I used COUNTA():

```
=COUNTA(B2:B5)
```

Then sort the data Horizonatally.

Choose just the data and the headers skipping the first column and hit the sort button on the data tab:

[image]

Then choose <kbd>Options</kbd> and choose `Sort left to right`.

Then choose your row with the counts and the <kbd>Order</kbd> to `Largest to Smallest`:

[image]

Then hit <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, this "helper row" technique was my first pass at this too, and it definitely provides a solution.Additionally, I like that this provides a count of the number of users in each AD group, which you could work some magic with, to provide percentages of users in each group, etc.  Not sure if I can mark multiple entries as answers (Stack newb) but thanks for the great explanation and screenshots!!

Comment: @3Jake you can only mark one as correct.  Mark the one that you will use.  None of use will get our feelings hurt if we are not chosen.  Thanks for the feed back.

Answer (score 1):

If the column/row set is relatively small here's a method:

[image]

1. Range B9:F13: `{=TRANSPOSE(A1:E5)}` (array formula `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`
2. Range A10: `=COUNTIF(C10:F10,"X")`
3. Range A11: `=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(COUNTIF(C11:F11,"X"),$A$10:A10,0)),COUNTIF(C11:F11,"X"),COUNTIF(C11:F11,"X")+0.1)` (to break ties), drag down
4. Copy Range A9:F13 to A16 as values and sort on `Count`
5. Range A23: `{=TRANSPOSE(B16:F20)}`
6. Copy | Paste Values and remove 0s from cells.

Comment: Thanks Scott, but I have about 3000 columns to screw around with, so I'm looking for something a little more automated - but thinking through this, it looks like your logic is spot-on :)